# How to create PySpark DataFrames if we have more no of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

`|CallID|            Customer             |                 Response           |
+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| 1    |Ready to repay the amount.        |He is ready to pay $50 by next week.|
| 2    |Mr. John's credit card is blocked.|Asked to verify last 3 transactions.|
| 3    |Mr. Tom is unable to pay bills.   |Asked to verify registered email add|
+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------`

I am selecting individual columns, performing Spelling Correction and joining them back. Here's my code:

**1. Selecting individual columns**

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from itertools import islice
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, col, asc
t = df.count()
newColumns = df.schema.names
df_t = df.select(df['Customer'])
s1 = ''
for i in range(t):
rdd = df_t.rdd
s = str(rdd.collect()[i][0])
s1 = s1 + '|' + s
text = str(TextBlob(s1).correct())
l = text.split('|')
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(l)
df1 = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x,)) \
.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda idx, it: islice(it, 1, None) if idx == 0 else 
it) \
.toDF([newColumns[1]])
s = s1 = rdd = rdd2 = text = ''
l = []
df_t = df.select(df['Response'])
for i in range(t):
rdd = df_t.rdd
s = str(rdd.collect()[i][0])
s1 = s1 + '|' + s
text = str(TextBlob(s1).correct())
l = text.split('|')
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(l)
df2 = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x,)) \
.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda idx, it: islice(it, 1, None) if idx == 0 else 
it) \
.toDF([newColumns[2]])`
```

**2. Joining them back**

```
df1 = df1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
df2 = df2.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
dffinal = df2.join(df1, "id", "outer").orderBy('id', 
ascending=True).drop("id")
```

**3. Final result**

`|        Customer                  |              Response              |
 +----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
 |Ready to repay the amount.        |He is ready to pay $50 by next week.|
 |Mr. John's credit card is blocked.|Asked to verify last 3 transactions.| 
 |Mr. Tom is unable to pay bills.   |Asked to verify registered email add|
 +----------------------------------+------------------------------------+`

This is a good approach if we have less no of columns. But is there a way to write a generalized code where we could create the DataFrames and join them based on no of columns just like an array or list of elements?

Comment: Using `monotonically_increasing_id` to join your DataFrames is not guaranteed to give you the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

```
##consider below array ##
    In [1]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                          'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                          'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                          'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                          index=[0, 1, 2, 3])


     In [8]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'E': ['B2', 'B3', 'B6', 'B7'],
                           'F': ['D2', 'D3', 'D6', 'D7'],
                          'G': ['F2', 'F3', 'F6', 'F7']},
                          index=[2, 3, 6, 7])

In [9]: result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, sort=False)
```